problem test spring using authentication pkce + jwt
I have a SpringBoot REST API that I'm having trouble running integration tests on.
I'm using Spring Security 3.3.0 with PKCE + JWT.
Before implementing security, the tests were working normally. Below is an example of my attempt to get it working again.
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.yml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {Base64ProtocolResolver.class})
class AmenitiesControllerIT {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseCleaner databaseCleaner;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();
        RestAssuredMockMvc.basePath = "v1/amenities";
        databaseCleaner.clearTables();
    }


    @Test
    @WithMockUser(
            username = "m@helixio.com.br",
            authorities = {
                    "SCOPE_READ",
                    "SCOPE_WRITE",
                    "GET_CONDOMINIUM"
            }
    )
    void shouldFilterAmenitiesPerCondominiumId_200() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("condominiumId", "1");

        given()
                .params(map)
                .get()
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .body("page.totalElements", is(1))
        ;
    }

When trying to do the test I got this error
jCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.restassured.internal.assertion.AssertParameter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 10 more

